# Sound from vibrating mobile

Tags: sounds

What are the best British words for the sound produced by a vibrating mobile?

Comment: Depending on the phone that might be a *buzz* or a *hum*

Comment: Or a *ringtone*. For example, you can download a software that is a "Free MP3 Ringtone Maker".

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can use ***[buzz](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buzz)***. According to Collins:

> ***noun***
>
> 1)  a rapidly vibrating humming sound, as that of a prolonged z or of a bee in flight
>      2) a low sound, as of many voices in conversation

Comment: In which context (particularly noting OP's reference to a *British* word) it's worth pointing out that in colloquial BrE, a ***buzz*** was used to mean a ***telephone call*** long before WW2, let alone mobile phones. But I don't know if it's a common usage in AmE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Before cell phones, one could say, "I'll give you a buzz" in the U.S., but maybe it wasn't as common as in British English, I'm not sure.  Anyway, the cell phone vibration sound can certainly be called a *buzz* now.

Comment: @aparente001: OED's first citation is GB Shaw (Irish). The second is from *Punch* (quintessentially British, I'd say), and the third is E Bowen *Death of Hearts* (Anglo-Irish). They're all before my time, but *buzz = [telephone] call* has been familiar to me since the 70s in BrE.